# Missing FileSystemPublish target for azure deployment

Tags: azure, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I try to get a asp.net5 Project to build with Visual Studio Online and deploy it to azure from there. I created the project with Visual Studio 2015 RTM.

I use the guide at [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/azure/deploy-aspnet5). The guide uses a msbuild target "FileSystemPublish" to get the build to azure. But I get the error that this target does not exist:

```
xxxx.sln.metaproj(0,0): Error MSB4057: The target "FileSystemPublish" does not exist in the project.
```

Does anyone know how I get this target working or how I can deploy without this target?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my mistake. I missed one step. I still tried to build the sln, but you need to build the xproj file:

> 7.Select the Visual Studio Build step and in the Solution input browse to the .xproj. Select it and click OK.

Comment: I did this but the Build process throws an parse error on the .xproj file... Anyone run into this?

Comment: Mine was working fine on the xproj file, but now we're getting the parse error as well. The project file itself hasn't changed, trying to narrow it down, but can't figure it out

Comment: Any updates? I'm hitting the same parse issue on the Visual Studio build step.